# undoing external dll reference from tfs

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs

When I undo an external dll in TFS, it looks as though it worked because I can compile with no errors. However, if I look in the folder where the dll lives it still shows the newest dll, which technically would not compile if I just did an Undo.

So, my question is, where does the old dll live after I do an Undo? Sorry, if sounds confusing.

Thanks,

rod.

Comment: Try cleaning the solution before recompiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what exactly do you undo? the reference of the project or the dll in a library-folder?

if you undo the "add reference" (so undo on the project file) the dll still exists where it was before (if you already did a build it also got copied to the output directory, where it stays - like mentioned by klausbyskov - until the next clean)

if you undo the adding of a dll in a folder (just the undo of a file) it remains on your harddrive until you delete it. it has never been on tfs.